# Best practices to display a promotion code area

Tags: e-commerce, vouchers

Promotion code can lead some traffic, and increase revenues.
At the same time, if a user is ready to buy without a promotion code, you shouldn't distract him with a too much visible promotion code area.

Do you have any recommandation on how to display a promotion code area?

For instance, here are 2 options, **maybe there are other options you can suggest**:

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information. I can't figure out why anyone would want to buy without a promotion code.

Comment: Are you talking about individual codes like `AS4NF2GE` or semi-public ones like `FALLDOWN` or both?

Comment: @StudentX so you always have a promotion code when you buy on Amazon?

Comment: @Crissov it can be both.

Comment: In my case promotion code is applied in the cart, right before I pay. Not on the product page.

Comment: @StudentX I've written "Buy (or any CTA)" to not be explicit about the page. So you can imagine that you are "in the cart".

Comment: Buy in the cart doesn't make sense to me, but anyway that's not the question here so let's move on.. have a look at my two cents in the answers below

Comment: "or any CTA", for instance "Add to cart".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the company wants to brand itself to it's audience. is it as a discount site or something more exclusive? If you choose to be the latter then option 2 is better.

Answer (score 0):

Users that see an empty text field will be more likely to want to fill that field with something. By hiding the field and only revealing it when the link or expand icon is clicked you are making it more optional, and reducing the amount of visual attention that it demands.

Answer (score 0):

- The first option, I feel, implies that all users have one or the other promo code. If this is not the case then user will feel annoyed.
- The most elegant way I feel is second one, when you are comparing the two.
- Moreover, many sellers are now putting all promo codes in their blog posts or offer pages or in Facebook posts etc (this also leads to more marketing and awareness) or in other channels like coupon stores.

Said that, all depends on your actual need and target customers that you have not clearly mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

**My two cents :** The first approach seems better, as it will prompt buyer to search for if the promotion code is available or not, and in the process they may find a promotion code for a different product and will be tempted to buy more.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like having a simple text link that, when clicked, expands a input works best for a lot of cases. If the user already has a discount code then they'll look for a link to apply it so a big call to action isn't needed.